# Highcharts.chart is not a constructor in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I have used Highchart in my .net core application but in few days before showing error `Highcharts.chart is not a constructor`.
I have see many site but didn't find any solution to render the highchart please help me. I have **10.3.3.1** version of Highchart.

we have to used following method for rendering the Highchart

```
var renderer = new HighchartsRenderer(chartOptions);

@Html.Raw(renderer.RenderHtml())
```

[Visit Our Blog for Solution](https://highartnewupdates.blogspot.com)

[SQL](https://diffclusterandnonclusterindex.blogspot.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduced your issue in my side and it came from the version of the js lib we referred to.

Pls pin the js lib version to v10.x like this:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/10.0.0/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/10.0.0/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

This is because highcharts already upgrade to v11, you can see [change log](https://www.highcharts.com/blog/changelog/#highcharts-v11.0.0) here. We have `Highsoft.Highcharts` which latest version is `10.3.3.1` but when we go to `https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js` we can see js file is already upgrade to V11.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution after reading the Highchart docx, actually problem in (new Highcharts.chart("chart",chartoption). So my new code like that.

This is my Controller Action method

```
 public IActionResult Index()
        {
            List<double> tokyoValues = new List<double> { 49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4 };
            List<double> nyValues = new List<double> { 83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0, 84.5, 105.0, 104.3, 91.2, 83.5, 106.6, 92.3 };
            List<double> berlinValues = new List<double> { 42.4, 33.2, 34.5, 39.7, 52.6, 75.5, 57.4, 60.4, 47.6, 39.1, 46.8, 51.1 };
            List<double> londonValues = new List<double> { 48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2 };
            List<ColumnSeriesData> tokyoData = new List<ColumnSeriesData>();
            List<ColumnSeriesData> nyData = new List<ColumnSeriesData>();
            List<ColumnSeriesData> berlinData = new List<ColumnSeriesData>();
            List<ColumnSeriesData> londonData = new List<ColumnSeriesData>();

            tokyoValues.ForEach(p => tokyoData.Add(new ColumnSeriesData
            {
                Y = p
            }));
            nyValues.ForEach(p => nyData.Add(new ColumnSeriesData
            {
                Y = p
            }));
            berlinValues.ForEach(p => berlinData.Add(new ColumnSeriesData
            {
                Y = p
            }));
            londonValues.ForEach(p => londonData.Add(new ColumnSeriesData
            {
                Y = p
            }));

            ViewData["tokyoData"] = tokyoData;
            ViewData["nyData"] = nyData;
            ViewData["berlinData"] = berlinData;
            ViewData["londonData"] = londonData;

            return View();
        }
```

And this is the updated view

```
@{
    chartOptions = new Highsoft.Web.Mvc.Charts.Highcharts
    {
        Title = new Title
        {
            Text = "Monthly Average Rainfall"
        },
        Subtitle = new Subtitle
        {
            Text = "Source: WorldClimate.com"
        },
        XAxis = new List<XAxis> {
            new XAxis {
              Categories = new List <string> {"Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"}
            }
          },
        YAxis = new List<YAxis> {
            new YAxis {
              Min = 0,
                Title = new YAxisTitle {
                  Text = "Rainfall (mm)"
                }
            }
          },

        Tooltip = new Tooltip
        {
            HeaderFormat = "<span style='font-size:10px'>{point.key}</span><table style='font-size:12px'>",
            PointFormat = "<tr><td style='color:{series.color};padding:0'>{series.name}: </td><td style='padding:0'><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>",
            FooterFormat = "</table>",
            Shared = true,
            UseHTML = true
        },

        PlotOptions = new PlotOptions
        {
            Column = new PlotOptionsColumn
            {
                PointPadding = 0.2,
                BorderWidth = 0
            }
        },

        Series = new List<Series>
{
                new ColumnSeries
                {
                    Name="New York",
                    Data=new List<ColumnSeriesData>
                    {
                            new ColumnSeriesData { Name = "Microsoft Internet Explorer", Y = 56.3, Drilldown = "Microsoft Internet Explorer" },
                            new ColumnSeriesData { Name = "Chrome", Y = 24.03, Drilldown = "Chrome" },
                            new ColumnSeriesData { Name = "Firefox", Y = 10.3, Drilldown = "Firefox" },
                            new ColumnSeriesData { Name = "Sfari", Y = 4.77, Drilldown = "Safari" },
                            new ColumnSeriesData { Name = "Opera", Y = 0.91, Drilldown = "Opera" },
                            new ColumnSeriesData { Name = "Proprietary or Undetectable", Y = 0.2, Drilldown = null }

                    }
        }
     }


    };

    chartOptions.ID = "chart";

    var renderer = new Highsoft.Web.Mvc.Charts.Rendering.HighchartsRenderer(chartOptions).RenderHtml();

    var renderer = renderer.Replace("new Highcharts.chart", "Highcharts.chart");

}

@Html.Raw(renderer)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).